# Junit parameterized names do not show up

Tags: junit4, parameterized

Hello I am running Junit 4.12 in my maven dependencies and the following sample code produces no errors, and runs perfectly fine, however, in eclipse neon, the parameterized names do not show up. All that shows are the indexes.

I spent a fair amount of time searching google and other stack overflow questions but have not seen anyone with a similar issues. Thanks for the help. [Attached is an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JV5n.png)

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: fib({0})={1}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }
           });
    }

    private int input;
    private int expected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(expected, Fibonacci.compute(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works as expected. Did you or Eclipse recompile the class after editing the parameter name? What happens when you add and run a failing test to your class, does Eclipse shows an error?

Comment: I ran the class again after updating the name, which I believe recompiles it. When I add a failing test the test fails as expected but produces no errors.